# Is it possible to define where the .bash_profile is located on the bash command line?

Tags: bash

I'm running bash programmatically from objective c to create a terminal-like application. Once launched I would like to execute some commands prior to turning control over to the user. Normally these would be in the `.bash_profile`. This file is not accessible to me and not something I would want to mess we anyway as I don't want to effect the standard bash environment for the user. I tried the `-c script.sh` switch but after script.sh is done running, bash exits. Are there any other options I have other than programmatically typing out the command I need run? I would rather not have the user see everything.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
bash --rcfile <your_rc_file> --noprofile -i
```

What the options mean:

- `--rcfile`: Use the following as the startup file
- `--noprofile`: Do not process the files `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `/etc/profile`, etc. Files used normally in login shell.
- `-i`: Its an interactive shell (kinda like opposite of `-c` which exits onces the argument to `-c` is processed).

The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) of `bash` is quite good. You could use it for more details on how bash can be launched.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke bash with  `--rcfile myfile` and have `test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` at the end of `myfile`.  This assumes you're launching an interactive but non-login shell.

For a login shell you would have to mimic bash's behavior with regard to `/etc/profile`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` and `.bash_logout`, which is tedious but doable.  You would still run `bash --rcfile myfile` but `myfile` would contain

```
test -r /etc/profile && source /etc/profile

for f in ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile
do
   if test -r $f
   then
      source $f
      break
   fi
done

trap 'source ~/.bash_logout' 0
```